# How to remove related files in Adobe dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am new to html and dreamweaver however I am trying to get rid of a tab and I am not sure how. I created a file and deleted it but I am not sure how to remove it from my related files which shows all the files at the top. Does anyone know how to. If I right click on the file all it says is open file in separate window.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ka1i.jpg)

Comment: Please ask this question here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions

Comment: Those "related files" are the files that are linked in the original document that is open, this is denoted with the "source code" button. The files will appear there as long as it's linked in the source document, whether it exists or not.